# Randomly selecting a limited number of records with two conditions in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a MySQL table with a column called "priority".  The column can have two values: high or low.  I want to select 8 records from the table at random, but I want 6 of them to be high priority, and 2 of them to be low priority.  If possibly, I would like to do it in one SQL statement.  Is there any way to do two LIMITS in one query based on this kind of criteria?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM table t1
 WHERE priority = 'high'
 ORDER BY rand() Limit 8
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.*
  FROM table t1
 WHERE priority = 'low'
 ORDER BY rand() Limit 2
```

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who came into the same problem I did, I got an error that said "Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY ". Then I found [this page](http://www.devchunks.com/code/incorrect-usage-of-union-and-order-by/) that tells you how to fix it. All you do is surround the query by parentheses. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

Use a union, so you have two select statements in one, basically.

Answer (score 0):

Use a union:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE priority = 'high' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table WHERE priority = 'low' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2
```